# In Eclipse, how do I sort the jars resolved by Ivy

Tags: eclipse, ivy, ivyde

I'm using IvyDE in Eclipse; it can resolve dependencies, but the resolved jars are not in order.

Is it possible to sort the jars alphabetically?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default option is to order by ivy.xml, however it can be changed in:

```
Window -> Preference -> Ivy -> Classpath Container
```

In `Order of the classpath entries`, change the default `From the ivy.xml` to `Lexical`.

The sorting is case sensitive, so `Z` goes before `a`. But it's good enough for my purpose.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The order comes from Ivy, which I'm guessing is the actual order in your ivy.xml.

Comment: you are right in saying the order is from ivy.xml, which can be changed. See details in my answer.